# IDX10803 and IDX10804 error with Azure AD

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

I have created a Web API in ASP.NET Core 2 and it is secured with Azure AD. The requests work fine in my dev environment. However when I publish the API to IIS and pass in a Authorization header in request I am getting these error:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
  Exception occurred while processing message.

System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established
```

What am I doing wrong? I can browse the url in browser successfully.

Comment: did you already check https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1116 and https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1062

Comment: Yes those are related to certificates issue. This is Azure AD so all certificates should be valid.

Comment: Check the account running your IIS apppool, It can be that your certificate is not trusted by that account.

Comment: @rawel I don't have any certificate. This is failing in calling Azure AD which I assume has valid certificates.

Comment: I was thinking it might be invalid from the perspective of the account running the app pool. You can try loading the URL from the account running the app pool to check if there are any warnings. Or try changing the app pool account to the same account you used to browse the URL.

Comment: @rawel My app is running under Application Pool Identity. How do I browse using that?

Comment: shift+right click the browser executable and select "run as different user" option. Sign-in with credentials used for app pool. But I'm not sure if I'm guiding you to a dead end. :-)

Comment: @rawel Found a solution. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I figured it out. It was because of a proxy setting to access the internet. Since ASP.NET Core does not pick up proxy setting from system.net area of web.config, the ideal solution was to create a middle ware to act as proxy.</strike>

I was running short of time. So I created a new user and logged on server with that new user and configured the proxy settings in Internet Explorer options. Then I configured the App Pool in IIS to run under that user's identity. Problem solved!

The correct answer is to add a proxy to the metadata request that ADAL makes using `BackchannelHttpHandler`. You can do it like this:

```
  public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
                {
                    options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        UseProxy = true,
                        Proxy = new WebProxy
                        {
                            Address = new Uri($"{appSettings.InternetProxyUrl}:{appSettings.InternetProxyPort}"),
                            UseDefaultCredentials = true
                        }
                    };
}
```